# Insert Text String Into href Link (Specific Location)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have links on a page that I wanted to add an ID Anchor too. This code I have works fine:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('#main > div > ul > li > a').attr('href',function(i,str) {
         return str + '#myAnchor';
    });
};
```

But sometimes because of the way the page is set up tracking gets added to the links so what is happening at the moment is I get http://www.myurl.com/#someannoyingtracking**#myAnchor** which doesn't anchor. How can I insert the anchor in between the URL or always after the ".com/" Like this: http://www.myurl.com/**#myAnchor**#someannoyingtracking

Comment: Why not just try `return '#myAnchor';` ?

Comment: `anchor = $('#main > div > ul > li > a')[0].pathname; anchor.hash = '#myHash' + anchor.hash` (or in a loop with multiple links)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) for that:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $('#main > div > ul > li > a').attr('href',function(i, str) {
        if (str.indexOf('#') > -1) {
            return str.replace('#', '#myAnchor');
        } else {
            return str + '#myAnchor';
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This worked by keeping the tracking there as well as incluiding my #anchor... Thanks CLyff

Answer (score 3):

This will insert an anchor before an annoying tracking anchor *or* at the end of the URL:

```js
$('#main > div > ul > li > a').attr('href', function(i,str) {
  return str.replace(/(\#.+)|($)/, '#myAnchor$1');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/#someannoyingtracking">Has anchor</a>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/">No anchor</a>
    </ul>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Rick, I didn't give you the correct answer because yours removes the tracking all together, although I gave you +1 because I will use this on a different page and it its useful to be able to remove something all together. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Understood, but note that this doesn't remove the tracking, it inserts the anchor before it.  So that may not work on your other page.

Comment: I think @Dug has the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Piggybacking on Rick Hitchcock's answer, but regex-free:

```js
$('#main > div > ul > li > a').each(function(index, elem) {
  elem.hash = '#myAnchor' + elem.hash;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/#someannoyingtracking">Has anchor</a>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/">No anchor</a>
    </ul>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Better than my answer!